# Easy way to get all user accounts

Tags: user-management, users

I am in the process of migrating to a new server and I am having a number of issues due to user accounts not being present (for example nginx seems to be running under nginx user on the new system www-data on the old system).

Is there an easy way to get all the user / group account information. (Ideally I would like to script the creation of new accounts with Ansible if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd  # show all users
cat /etc/group   # show all groups
```

You can then pipe the output to other programs/scripts for further processing.

Answer (score 8):

How to list all users and groups depends on how authentication is configured.

The most basic are the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files used for local authentication.

Using those files is insufficient to get a complete listing when user/group data is stored centrally, for instance in LDAP, NIS, Hesiod, etc.

Central authentication is usually configured **in addition to** the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files to allow the system to be booted and viable in single user mode by means of the Name Service Switch configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

If configured with NSS:

```
getent passwd
```

will show **all user accounts**: both those from `/etc/passwd` and your central user directory.

```
getent group
```

will show **all groups**.

By monitoring the exit status of the `getent` command you will also know if you did indeed list all users/groups (exit code `0`) or that you're missing some (exit code `3` indicates a database that does not support enumeration and you'll need to use appropriate tools for that specific database...).

Comment: To further complicate matters `sssd.conf` defaults to `enumerate: FALSE` and still causes `getent` to return 0.